# Владеть и обладать

Tags: лингвистика

Слова "владеть" и "обладать" - синонимы. Но почему же тогда можно сказать "владеть языком", но нельзя "обладать языком"?

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/448093/%d0%9e%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1

Answer (score 1):

Слово владеть - многозначное. Каждое значение слова может иметь свой синонимический и антонимический ряд. В одном из значений: иметь что-либо в своей собственности - слова владеть и обладать являются синонимами. В другом значении: уметь обращаться, искусно действовать - эти слова синонимами не являются.