# Особенности приставки об-

Tags: этимология, приставка

Действительно ли этимологические корни всех этих слов начинаются с буквы В?

*Обладать,
область,
обратить,
обернуть,
обращение,
оборот,
облечь,
облако,
обедать,
обещать,
обет,
обида,
обетшать,
обязать,
обуза,
обитать,
оболочка,
ободок,
обоз,
обычно,
обонять,
обильно.*

Comment: кто говорит что они начинаются на в?

Comment: @qdinar ну вроде ведь есть же слова завет, навет, ответ, привет, но обет,  тоже самое и с отведать, но обедать

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/449895/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2

Answer (score 1):

> Действительно ли этимологические корни всех этих слов начинаются с
>   буквы В?

Ну, судя по всему, да. Здесь надо оговорить две вещи.

Первая та, что понятие "этимологический корень" рассматривается предельно широко, то есть в предположении, что к этимологически однокоренным словам относятся все формы корня, независимо от того, как на самом деле они образовались - через чередование, протезу или, наоборот, усечение исходного варианта. Оговорка эта не лишняя, поскольку в наших примерах "в" может возникать именно как протетическое, при исходном этимологическом корне без этого звука (или с другим). О протезах есть в вики https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0

И вторая оговорка про слово "обедать", которое тут уже упоминалось. Дело в том, что отношения корней "вед(ать)" и "ед(а)" весьма запутаны, непонятно, родственны ли они, и если да, то на каком уровне. Более того, непонятно даже, что первично в корне ед/вед, является ли "в" (в "отведать", "медведь" = мед едящий) результатом вторичного фонетического процесса или же наоборот, первичным, но исчезнувшим во всех остальных примерах. Понятно другое, "вед" и "ед" к моменту образования слов "обед" и "отведать" уже разошлись настолько (если вообще были родственными), что говорить об истинном этимологическом родстве не приходится. Поэтому и нужна данная оговорка.

А в остальном - да, все корни имеют (или когда-то имели) среди прочих и форму с лидирующим "в". Такая формулировка, пожалуй, не встретит возражений - в отличие от упоминания об этимологическом корне.

> Обет, обида, обитать, обычно - эти сомнительно. Обильно - это вряд ли.
>   Обетшать - это что-то старинное.

Да, тут есть некоторые проблемы. Но они решаемы.
обет - завет
обычно - ср. чрезвычайно.
обида - завидовать (поверьте, один корень)
обетшать - просто диалектная форма для обветшать. Непонятно, как в этот список попало.

Answer (score 0):

Попытаюсь ответить, хотя не уверен, что Вы спросили то, что хотели спросить.

Корни приведенных слов можно посмотреть в специальных словарях, например, Тихонова или Кузнецовой и Ефремовой.

Для ускорения / упрощения поиска я делал проверку по Викисловарю, который ссылается на указанные словари.

Результаты:
Корень слова **облечь** начинается на букву **л**, а корни остальных слов — на букву **о**.

Что касается этимологии, действительно, можно заметить, что большинство этих слов (за редким исключением) образовано от корней, которые начинались на букву **в** (согласно словарю Фасмера; проверял я в основном тоже в Викисловаре, но некоторые по этимологическим словарям).

Пример исключения: слово **обедать**, которое происходит от корня **ед**.

Comment: словари к определению корня подходят морфологически, т.е. чисто формально, а не семантически, что по-моему является правильным методом

Comment: **обедать** может происходить и от корня **вед**, как например **отведать**, (который также связан с едой), но с редукцией начальной **В** под влиянием предлога, и потому, что он согласуется с акцентной парадигмой других глаголов с этим корнем, ***проведать, поведать, разведать, изведать, наведаться***, сочетание корня **-ед-** с приставкой **об-** уже реализовано в глаголе **объедать**, но здесь они разделяются йотированием и акцентная парадигма глаголов с этим корнем отличается от вышеупомянутой, ***доедать, переедать, надоедать, недоедать, съедать, разъедать, поедать***