# Особенности изменения корней слов

Tags: морфология, морфемика

В Интернете встретил задание.

Выберите из пяти слов лишнее, которое отличается от остальных четырех слов тем, что в нём НЕТ особенности, связанной с необычным изменением изначального корня слова: 1. оборот 2. ободок 3.оболочка 4. обонять 5. обожать

Ответ: оболочка.

Я не очень понимаю, в чем состоит необычность изменения корня. Если просклонять или проспрягать данные слова, мы увидим, что ни один корень не изменится.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Конечно, в таких случаях просто необходимо пояснение составителя задания — бог знает, что у него на уме было...

На мой взгляд, правильный ответ все-таки 5 (обожать), и вот почему:

все остальные слова исторически имели начальный звук *в* в корне, который в процессе развития языка «выпал», потому что, видимо, сочетания *обво* неудобно произносить. Иными словами, оборот < *об**в**орот (ср. вращать, воротить), обод(ок) < *об**в**од (ср. водить), оболочка < *об**в**олочка (ср. обволочь), обонять < *об**в**онять (ср. вонять).

Слово *обожать* же производно от слова *бог*.

Comment: Отличный ответ! Согласна с Вами: лишнее слово ОБОЖАТЬ.

Comment: Aer, я видел этот вопрос в интернете. Тоже не понял. С какой точки зрения подходить: с синхронической или диахронической. Однако, полагаю, вы, наверное, правы.